# Grails 3.2.9 setup issue in Windows

Tags: grails

I am moving from grails 2.5.1 to grails 3.2.9 (On Windows). I downloaded the latest zip file for grails 3.2.9. Then changed GRAILS_HOME to point to the new version and changed PATH to have GRAILS_HOME\bin.

I then executed 
grails --version to confirm that the right version of grails is running.

I then created a grails app using
grails create-app bgrt2

When i execute the grails app using
grails run-app, I get a gradle error pasted below. Any help is appreciated.

C:\work3\bgrt2>
| Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\work3\bgrt2\build.gradle' line: 19
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'bgrt2'.

  > org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

CONFIGURE FAILED

Total time: 6.631 secs
| Error Error initializing classpath: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly remove all the cached files in the Gradle cache location

> C:\Users[Your_Username].gradle\caches

Then run this command to refresh you gradle

> gradle --refresh-dependencies build

N.B. Grails 2 and Grails 3 is fully different where there is no `config.groovy` in Grails 3. You need to configure everything in `application.yml`
You need to define your project name in `application.yml`at line no. 5 as like

> defaultPackage: bgrt2